# Deploy a WCF service on a non sharepoint Environemnt

Tags: web-services, wcf, sharepoint

I have a WCF service that uses the DLL : Microsoft.sharepoint

When I deployed it to the server that does not have sharepoint installed on it then I got the below error :

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies

Can anyone help me with this issue ?

Comment: Did you include the `Microsoft.SharePoint` DLL in the bin folder of the service?

Comment: Also note, that you may not actually be allowed to simply copy the DLL with your application. Check out [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/32184) for further information. (Or google "sharepoint assembly redistribution").

Comment: If in your code use Sharepoint Object Model, the deploy of the dll is not sufficient but require Sharepoint Installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I figured out that I can not using server side object model on an environment that does not have SharePoint installed on it. to solve the issue I created a new service that calls the old one ex: make the old one as a client in the new one . using so I will not need to have the SharePoint farm installed on the server hosting the service

Comment: You can deploy a WCF service that uses SharePoint web services in it but not the object model directly unless it is on a SharePoint dedicated front end server.